# VBScript to query namespace value and if % then run X.bat

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wmic, tpm

I'm trying to VBScript a process to check the TPM namespace onboard a PC (because I believe it's not possible as a batch file) and if it's version 2.0, return a "YES" echo prompt but so far it appears to only return a FALSE value even though I know the correct result is TRUE (2.0, 0, 1.16).

If I can get the "TPM SpecVersion" into my `If` statement, I'll eventually have the script run a downgrade utility during PXE builds but I'm just using echo for now so I can get the identification of TPM version figured out.

This is what I've hacked together so far (`dev2.vbs`):

```
Dim strTPM
strTPM = "wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm path win32_tpm get SpecVersion"

If strTPM = "%2.0%" Then
    WScript.Echo "YES"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Nup"
End If
```

I know I can run the `wmic` query in Command Prompt and get the correct TPM version but I can't seem to get that result to present itself correctly in this script. I get an echo pop-up of "Nup" every time.

I've tried a few alternative syntaxes from VBScripts online that reference active services, including the following, but they all error and don't even produce a FALSE echo result.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_TPM WHERE SpecVersion='%2.0%'")
For Each objtpm In colItem
    Return = objSpecVersion.Value()
    If Return = "%2.0%" Then
        WScript.Echo "YES YES YES"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Nup"
    End If
Next
```

Could anyone please help me get the namespace lookup result to filter down to the `If..Else` statements below it?

I'd like to avoid PowerShell if I can.

Comment: WMI is available from command prompt via wmic or ALL OTHER COM or .NET languages. So you are wrong.

Comment: So what does it return instead of `"%2.0%"`?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your comparison string (`%2.0%`) you're trying to do a partial match on the version string. However, the operators you're using are for *exact* matches. Not to mention that your first code snippet cannot work at all, because you never actually execute the command string you defined.

Change the filter clause in your [WQL query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wql-sql-for-wmi) from `SpecVersion='%2.0%'` to `SpecVersion LIKE '%2.0%'` and also use the correct variable (`objtpm` instead of the undefined `objSpecVersion`) and the code should produce the intended result.

```
found = False
qry   = "SELECT * FROM Win32_TPM WHERE SpecVersion LIKE '%2.0%'"
For Each objtpm In objWMIService.ExecQuery(qry)
    found = True
Next

If found Then
    WScript.Echo "Yes"
Else
    WScript.Echo "No"
End If
```

Alternatively remove the filter clause from the query and do a partial comparison with the `InStr` function inside the loop:

```
qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_TPM"
For Each objtpm In objWMIService.ExecQuery(qry)
    specVerion = objtpm.SpecVersion
    If InStr(specVersion, "2.0") > 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "Yes"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "No"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Object required: 'objWMIService' with both of your suggestions.

Comment: @gerendasi My answer does not provide a turnkey solution. You need to integrate it with your existing code. Consider this your homework.